# Anime about a male character who died in a bicycle accident

Tags: story-identification, anime

In the anime I am searching for, the main character dies by bicycle accident (from what I remember) and the anime continues with him as a ghost/spirit or something.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Roughly when did you watch this? And can you recall any other details about the characters or plot? If so, please [edit] them into your question.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: https://myanimelist.net/manga/8972/Koisuru_Cupid - (Manga, not anime)

Comment: Maybe [YuYu Hakusho](https://yuyuhakusho.fandom.com/wiki/YuYu_Hakusho)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but I've found a listing for a manga novel about a boy named Harumi, who died while riding his bicycle.

The English title is *[Cheat Skill: "Sleep Learning" ~Heartwarmingly Living the Other World Life~](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=129961)*

Description:

> In a Fantasy World of Swords and Magics.
>
> Harumi who died from dozing off while driving his bicycle have come to another world with the peerless skill 『Sleep Learning』.
>
> It is the story of Harumi with his life at stake to sleep.

Comment: If this answer is correct, please upvote it and mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark just beneath the voting arrows.